# ¿Como puedo usar sync para mandarle parámetros adicionales a la tabla pivote?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una relación de **muchos a muchos** con los modelos **Fiesta** y **Paquete**, en el paquete trae los id de los platillos que contiene ese paquete (Los id los obtiene de una relación de muchos a muchos de una relación con el modelo **Productos**). Lo que quiero hacer es almacenar en la tabla pivote **fiesta_paquete** dos campos extra, aparte de los id de las dos tablas relacionadas **(fiesta_id, paquete_id)**, el nombre de los platillos que se servirán para los niños y para los adultos.

**Modelo Fiesta**

```
public function paquetes(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Paquete', 'fiesta_paquete', 
            'paquete_id', 'fiesta_id')
            ->withPivot('comidaNino', 'comidaAdulto')
            ->withTimestamps();  
}
```

**Modelo Paquete**

```
public function fiestas(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Fiesta', 'fiesta_paquete', 
         'paquete_id', 'fiesta_id')
          ->withPivot('comidaNino', 'comidaAdulto')
          ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Esta es la migración de la tabla pivote **fiesta_paquete**:

```
Schema::create('fiesta_paquete', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('paquete_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('fiesta_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('comidaNino')->nullable();
            $table->text('comidaAdulto')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('paquete_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('paquetes')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('fiesta_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('fiestas')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

He intentado mandarle al sync un array pero no funciona. Los datos los recojo de un formulario para crear la fiesta, en el cual tengo 3 select dinamicos en los cuales dependiendo del paquete que seleccione se muestran los platillos, de los cuales se pueden seleccionar varios.

Al momento de crearla me aparece este error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`new_guercos`.`fiesta_paquete`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fiesta_paquete_paquete_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`paquete_id`)
>   REFERENCES `paquetes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into
>   `fiesta_paquete` (`created_at`, `fiesta_id`, `paquete_id`,
>   `updated_at`) values (2019-10-08 05:53:35, 2, 9, 2019-10-08 05:53:35))

Y viendo los datos que se envían por post están los dos arrays de platillos el de niños y adultos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el script que uso para intentar guardar los datos en la tabla pivote:

```
$paquete_id = $request->input('paquete');
$comidaNino = $request->input('comidaNino');
$comidaAdulto = $request->input('comidaAdulto');

$fiesta->paquetes()->sync($paquete_id, array(
        'comidaNino' => (array)$comidaNino,
        'comidaAdulto' => (array)$comidaAdulto
));
```

Comment: que es lo que quieres guardar en esas columnas? veo que en la migración son de tipo texto, pero quieres insertarle arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sync deberías pasarle un array con la id del paquete relacionado como clave, y como valor, otro array con las claves/valor de las columnas adicionales. Algo así:

```php
$paquete_id = 1;// request('paquete_id');
$fiesta->paquetes()->sync([
    $paquete_id => [
            'comidaNino' => implode(",", $comidaNino),
            'comidaAdulto' => implode(",", $comidaAdulto),
    ]
]);
```

Y ten en cuenta que para este caso tienes arrays para guardar en la columna, y típicamente no guardas arrays, sino texto/json o numero. por eso el `implode`, que no necesariamente iría, y podría ser:

```php
// si la columna es texto
$comidaNino = 'burritos,baguette';// implode(",", $comidaNino);
// si la columna es una fk
$comidaNino = $comida_id; // integer
$fiesta->paquetes()->sync([
    $paquete_id => [
            'comidaNino' => $comidaNino,
            'comidaAdulto' => $comidaAdulto,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me ha funcionado.

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo planteamiento y situación que la resuelta en este hilo pero en mi caso al aplicar la solución me devuelve un error del tipo "Error: Illegal offset type". ¿A qué puede ser debido?. Gracias.

Comment: @jmrufo probablemente a cómo estés armando el array. En la clave, debe ir la id (un número entero) y en el valor para esa clave, un subarray con columnas adicionales